# NoMethodError - undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth to try to signup/login users on my web app.
This is happening inside my `AuthenticationsController#Create` method:

Authentications Controller:

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def create
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:success] = "Signed in successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect(authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      token = omniauth['credentials'].token
      secret = omniauth['credentials'].secret
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => token_secret)
      flash[:success] = "Authentication successful"
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save!
        flash[:success] = "Account created"
        sign_in(authentication.user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to '/signup'
      end
    end
  end
```

I originally had `sign_in(:user, authentication.user)` but it gave me argument errors, so I changed it to just `had sign_in(authentication.user)` in the above code. However, now I'm getting a `NoMethodError - undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Line 23 `sign_in(authentication.user)` is failing because you are in the else branch of `if authentication` condition (so `authentication` is nil).
What you probably meant to do is call `sign_in(user)` for user you just created a few lines above.

Comment: I changed it to `sign_in_and_redirect(user)` but I'm still getting undefined local variable or method `user'

Answer (score 0):

First you test if `authentication` is defined, and then in the `else` block, which will only trigger if it is not defined, you go and reference `authentication.user` for some reason. This could not possibly work.

That condition seems to apply if you haven't authenticated, and aren't logged in. Why would you be engaging the `sign_in` function under those circumstances?

Comment: what should the correct "def create" for this controller look like? I tried to follow the Railscast for omniauth

Answer (score 0):

If your using a set list of providers in your db make sure

```
> :provider => omniauth['provider']
```

Matches up with the provider in the db, for instance. If you have `facebook_Oauth2` in your db and the provider response is `facebook` authenthication will fail.